# Is initialization of a static value with an inline function an initialization with a constant expression?

Tags: c++

A constexpr function is a constant expression. Is an inline function considered a constant expression during initialization of a static value?

```
constexpr int constexpr_add_one(int x) { return x + 1; } // implies inline
inline int inline_add_one(int x) { return x + 1; }

static const int constexpr_value = constexpr_add_one(0xaaaa0000);
static const int inline_value = inline_add_one(0xbbbb0000);

// Aside:
// static constexpr int another_constexpr_value = constexpr_add_one(0xcccc0000);
// error: call to non-constexpr function ‘int inline_add_one(int)’
// static constexpr int another_inline_value = inline_add_one(0xdddd0000);

volatile int value;

int main() {
    value = constexpr_value;
    value = inline_value;
}
```

Does the C++ Standard provide a definition of 'constant expression' (which night be no 'constexpr')?

I use g++ 4.8.4

Comment: What happens if you change the value declarations to: `static constexpr int` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten It is an error for the inline case.

Comment: No, may be in this example compiler can do a lot of heavy optimization to generate an extremely minimal assembly, but in debug build, `inline_one` would have usual call semantics whereas `constexpr_one` would just be direct calculated value (at compile time) assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Rules for `static` values initialization are speaking only about `constexpr` not `inline` functions.

`constexpr` implies `inline` but `inline` doesn't imply `constexpr`. Just pick any of rules for function to be `constexpr` below and let your function break it. Such function could still be made `inline` though.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

> A constexpr specifier used in a function declaration implies inline.
>
> A constexpr function must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - it must not be virtual
> - its return type must be LiteralType
> - each of its parameters must be LiteralType
> - there exists at least one argument value such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant
>     expression (for constexpr function templates, at least one
>     specialization must satisfy this requirement , for constructors, use
>     in a constant initializer is sufficient) (since C++14))
> - the function body must be either deleted or defaulted or contain only the following:
>
>   - null statements
>   - static_assert declarations
>   - typedef declarations and alias declarations that do not define classes or enumerations
>   - using declarations
>   - using directives
>   - exactly one return statement. (until C++14)
> - the function body must be either deleted or defaulted or contain any statements except:
>
>   - an asm declaration
>   - a goto statement
>   - a statement with a label other than case and default
>   - a try-block
>   - a definition of a variable of non-literal type
>   - a definition of a variable of static or thread storage duration
>   - a definition of a variable for which no initialization is performed.
>   - if the function is a defaulted copy/move assignment, the class of which it is a member must not have a mutable variant member You can
>       make functions that are definitely non-`constexpr` in any sensible way
>       `inline`.

E. g.
parameter not literal

```
inline void f1(const std::string&) { }
```

a definition of a variable of non-literal type

```
inline void f1() { std::string a; }
```

a try-block

```
inline void f1() { try { int a = 0; } catch(...) {} }
```

EDIT:
Standard does define "constant expression". Definition is rather long. Maybe you could check it here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression

Comment: Not "constexpr", but "A constant initializer for an object o is an expression that is a **constant expression**, [...]"

Comment: Ok. My impression was that from all possible constant expressions you are interested in constexpr only. Still result of static function call is not always constant expression. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression

Comment: Not a very useful answer because you're just shooting in the dark.